# Can I add a NSMutablearray to the NSMutableArray in an object in another array

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsmutablearray

Is it possible to add a `NSMutableArray` to a `NSMutableArray`?

And if so how can I access the objects (and `objects ivars`)in the added array
Thanks

Ok I need to make my question better represent my issue.

In array 1 I have a number of objects of type person, has a dictionary to store person info
In array 2 I have one object of type city, has an array meant to store person.
In array 3 I have one object of type country, has an array to store city.

What I would like to do is take all the person and store them in the city array meant to hold person. Then take the city and store in country array meant to hold city.

After that has been done I would like to be able to parse the data to be able to look for a particular person. So look in the final array find the country, then in the subarray find the city, then in the next subarray find the person.

Hopefully I have not made my question unclear.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
NSMutableArray *combo = [[array1 mutableCopy] addObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

And to get any object, simply use:

`yourElement = [combo objectAtIndex:yourIndex]`.

Comment: an even quicker way to access the content of the array is by using `combo[yourIndex];`

Comment: @NikolasBurk I agree.